# Very slow export to pdf (latex) in org mode Windows10

Tags: windows, emacs, latex, org-mode, pdflatex

I'm using Spacemacs on Windows 10, using mainly orgmode. However when I export the .org file to pdf, it takes like 40-60 seconds to compile. I have MikTex installed and compiling latex through vimtex or texstudio is not slow. Any suggestions what might be the cause of all this?

Comment: Divide and conquer: Export to tex and then compile the tex file manually: that will at least tell you which is the slow process (or maybe both are).

Comment: The compilation is the slow one, emacs tex export is almost instant.